# Как разрешить доступ в инет только через VPN?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, vpn

Цель - отключить инет соединение, если отстуствует VPN. Т.е. маршрутизировать его через VPN-соединение. Пинг у меня заработал, но днс чёт не встали. Подскажите где косяк?

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d xx.xx.154.17 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tap+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

И еще - если vpn-выключен как разрешить доступ только в локалхост